# No access to keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on a medion akoya E7424 Notebook. Everything looks good but I cannot input anything from Keyboard. It Looks as there is no Driver. So what can I do ?

Comment: try a newer version like 16.04.2 or 17.04, and test the keyboard in live mode first before installing.